# Can I return to the Schengen area without my residency permit?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany

I'm living in Germany with a blue card. Some days ago I've come to Korea but I forgot to take my blue card. I'm going back to Germany from Incheon airport (Seoul) and will stop over in Heathrow airport (London) and will go back to Tegel airport (Berlin).

How can I go back to Berlin without my blue card? I can ask my wife to bring the card to Tegel airport if it would help, but I'm not sure if I can take the flight at Heathrow airport or even at Incheon airport.

**Update**

I've asked via another channel and just got an answer saying that he had accidentally put his blue card in the baggage but he was able to enter the country after the security guy checked through the system. That said, more official answer would be welcome.

**Update 2**

I've come to Germany without any problem, but it was possible as I had *Beiblatt* attached to my passport, which has the expiration date of my visa. The staff at the check-in desk has checked the document and the German border guard also has checked it. Nobody asked me for the blue card in my case. So I don't know what would have happened if I had neither.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I have Korean citizenship.

Comment: Have you considered to get the document shipped to Korea? I wouldn't put it into an ordinary letter, but many express delivery companies have "premium services" with parcel tracking, mostly assured delivery times, signatures at both ends, etc.

Comment: @o.m. Yes i have, but I gave up on that as I found that I might not be able to get it before my flight.

Comment: When you say you left your _blue card_, do you mean your _Aufenthaltstitel_ card, which is this blue-ish/purple card that looks like a national ID, and is only valid together with your passport? The §19a visa does not necessarily come with that card. For some time Berlin for example uses full-page stickers because Bundesdruckerei had too much of a backlog creating cards. In that case, you could not have forgotten the visa. Anyway, a third compound is the _Beiblatt_ that states which job you are allowed to do. Do you have that, maybe stuck into the cover of your passport?

Comment: @simbabque Yes, I meant Aufenthaltstitel card. If it doesn't need to come with my passport I am more relieved. I have the sticker attached in my passport but that one is for temporary ise and already expired. I have the third one,  the Beiblatt, with my passport as you guessed and I found a valid date in it. I now thing it would be enough for me. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Well that card is only valid as a visa if it is with your passport. So you should have it with you if you travel, as it's also your Schengen visa. But that _Beiblatt_ is probably a good start for convincing the German border people that you have a valid visa. For the entry part, you can also write Bundespolizei on Twitter. They are very responsive. No clue how the UK think about that, though.

Comment: @simbabque Ah, okay I misunderstood a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a citizen of South Korea you are free to visit the Schengen area without a visa, since your country is on the [Annex II list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#Citizens_of_.27Annex_II.27_countries_and_territories_.28Visa_waiver_countries.29). You could therefore exit Germany without any issues. As for the return - while the German border guards might want to see your residency card, it's not really necessary for entry as they have access to the database of people with German residency. However you *might* face an issue with **the airline** as they're technically supposed to verify you haven't exhausted the 90/180 days limit in the Schengen area. In this case you would have to either:

- Hope nobody would bother checking and simply show up for the flight, which is usually the case in my experience
- Apply for a temporary visa at the German consulate
- Get a fresh South Korean passport (or a second passport) that doesn't have any Schengen entry stamps
- Purchase a transit flight *via* Germany to another country (e.g. the UK) and fly without luggage. In this case you would simply exit in Germany before reaching your final destination.

If you were a citizen of a country whose nationals require a visa to enter the Schengen area, your only option would've been to receive a temporary visa before leaving or at the consulate.

Source: being in the very same situation in the Czech Republic.

Comment: Since the OP is currently living in Germany, I would expect that he has already spent more than 90 out the previous 180 days in Germany or more generally in the Schengen area and is therefore not allowed to reenter using only his visa-free (Annex II based) 'allowance'. You are right that German immigration police will have access to and is able to verify the residence permit, but the airline is not. It is very likely that the airline will deny boarding, since he is not allowed to enter Germany based on the documents he will present when checking in.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo do airlines actually verify the 90/180 rule? What I usually saw was that the clerk simply checks the passport validity and that's it. Worst case scenario OP could fly *via* Germany (e.g. on Lufthansa) on a fake transit and then simply exit at the layover airport.

Comment: Since I am an EEA citizen, I have never been subject to the 90/180 rule when flying to a Schengen country myself, but I would be very surprised if the airlines don't check that. German immigration law is not very specific, but states that the air carriers are responsible for the passengers to be carrying travel documents and being entitled to enter. I would be very surprised if the airline is *not* sanctioned with a fine if they bring a passenger to Germany, who is not allowed to enter because the 90 days are 'used up'.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo answer updated

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: how would the airline check the 90/180 days? If they have access to the database, they can also see that the OP is a residen; if they don't, how could they verify?

Comment: @MartinArgerami passport stamps. That's also how Schengen border guards do the check as there's no Schengen-wide entry-exit database (yet).

Comment: @MartinArgerami Which "the database"? The airline would use the entry and exit stamps in the passport to calculate previous stays, just as immigration officers do when you are entering the Schengen area.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I have flown to the Schengen area using a US passport without any attempt to verify my 90-180 status, and indeed at times when I would have appeared to be in violation of the rule, although not in the last 10 years or so.  But the airline could challenge the traveler who is arriving in Schengen without any obvious plans to leave.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Do you have any evidence of that? I have flown to Europe some 40 times, from 8 different countries in three continents, with many airlines, and I have never seen a check-in employee perusing the many stamps in my passport to verify my last Schengen exit; which, by the way, could perfectly be in my other passport, as happened twice this year.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: as I mentioned to Jonathan, that is in strong disagreement with my experience. And even then, if that were the case, the traveller can solve the "issue" by getting a new passport. Are you saying that it is that easy for an over-stayed traveller to reenter the Schengen area? Just get a new passport?

Comment: @MartinArgerami you can indeed abuse the 90/180 limit by getting a fresh passport and flying to a different country.

Comment: They should be able to get an excerpt from the _Ausländerzentralregister_ as well, which contains their name and visa status. But I believe that also requires a written application, so not useful for short notice. The [Bundespolizei suggests](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/95109/6792) to carry that around if your passport is with an embassy in case you get into a police control.